Idea for a Puzzle Challenge Theme
Not sure if there is a set place/question I should relay this, but I have an idea for a puzzle challenge theme:
Red Herring-Centered Puzzles
All puzzles submitted must include at least one red herring, but preferably many. Even better might be to include many levels of red herring paths. Of course, creativity is desired, and imagination is your only boundary.
I'm not sure if this theme has already been done, and if so, maybe disregard this idea. If not, I think it could be really fun. Makes me wish that I already had a good red herring-themed puzzle, but I don't! But I will!

The most recent topic challenge idea post (i.e. where you would post ideas) eventually fizzled out; if you want to run another topic challenge you'd have to organize the event again.

Yeah, so what happened with the last one is that we turned off the bot for the Advent Calendar in December and it just never got turned back on again. We often end up with cyclical on-and-offs like this though, so nothing to say we can't get it started again some time. I'd suggest posting it as an answer on the meta post linked in bobble's comment above. If we start up some activity on that post again, it may spark further interest and ultimately catalyse things going once more...
